# Is Snapshot feature available with OpenEBS cStor?

Tags: openebs

I am using OpeNEBS 0.7.2 cStor version and I am unable to create cStor volume snapshot. It show following errors.

```
E1129 18:49:42.581577       1 processor.go:82] failed to create snapshot for volume :pvc-845b429c-f34e-11e8-bea9-021288b303ec, err: Get http://:9501/v1/volumes: dial tcp :9501: connect: connection refused
W1129 18:49:42.581601       1 snapshotter.go:269] failed to snapshot &v1.PersistentVolumeSpec{Capacity:v1.ResourceList{"storage":resource.Quantity{i:resource.int64Amount{value:5368709120, scale:0}, d:resource.infDecAmount{Dec:(*inf.Dec)(nil)}, s:"5Gi", Format:"BinarySI"}}, PersistentVolumeSource:v1.PersistentVolumeSource{GCEPersistentDisk:(*v1.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)(nil), AWSElasticBlockStore:(*v1.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)(nil), HostPath:(*v1.HostPathVolumeSource)(nil), Glusterfs:(*v1.GlusterfsVolumeSource)(nil), NFS:(*v1.NFSVolumeSource)(nil), RBD:(*v1.RBDPersistentVolumeSource)(nil), ISCSI:(*v1.ISCSIPersistentVolumeSource)(0xc42051de00), Cinder:(*v1.CinderPersistentVolumeSource)(nil), CephFS:(*v1.CephFSPersistentVolumeSource)(nil), FC:(*v1.FCVolumeSource)(nil), Flocker:(*v1.FlockerVolumeSource)(nil), FlexVolume:(*v1.FlexPersistentVolumeSource)(nil), AzureFile:(*v1.AzureFilePersistentVolumeSource)(nil), VsphereVolume:(*v1.VsphereVirtualDiskVolumeSource)(nil), Quobyte:(*v1.QuobyteVolumeSource)(nil), AzureDisk:(*v1.AzureDiskVolumeSource)(nil), PhotonPersistentDisk:(*v1.PhotonPersistentDiskVolumeSource)(nil), PortworxVolume:(*v1.PortworxVolumeSource)(nil), ScaleIO:(*v1.ScaleIOPersistentVolumeSource)(nil), Local:(*v1.LocalVolumeSource)(nil), StorageOS:(*v1.StorageOSPersistentVolumeSource)(nil), CSI:(*v1.CSIPersistentVolumeSource)(nil)}, AccessModes:[]v1.PersistentVolumeAccessMode{"ReadWriteOnce"}, ClaimRef:(*v1.ObjectReference)(0xc420486f50), PersistentVolumeReclaimPolicy:"Delete", StorageClassName:"openebs-cstor-disk", MountOptions:[]string(nil), VolumeMode:(*v1.PersistentVolumeMode)(nil), NodeAffinity:(*v1.VolumeNodeAffinity)(nil)}, err: Get http://:9501/v1/volumes: dial tcp :9501: connect: connection refused
E1129 18:49:42.581694       1 goroutinemap.go:150] Operation for "createdefault/snapshot-cstor-postgres-data-a9defa6b-f406-11e8-bea9-021288b303ecpostgres-data" failed. No retries permitted until 2018-11-29 18:51:44.581673306 +0000 UTC m=+97194.100277390 (durationBeforeRetry 2m2s). Error: "Failed to take snapshot of the volume pvc-845b429c-f34e-11e8-bea9-021288b303ec: %!q(<nil>)"
```

Are snapshots supported with cstor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.7 had a preview version of snapshot of cStor Engine the above mentioned issue has been fixed in 0.8 revision.

Note -- Snaphot feature has enhanced and clone feature has been introduced with 0.8 OpenEBS version.